# Simplifing integral with known function

Tags: improper-integrals, gamma-function

can someone help me to prove that the following integral can be writting as follows:

$$ I= \int_{0}^\infty (1- \frac{1}{(1+c\cdot r^{-\alpha})^n}) 2r\cdot dr = c^{2/\alpha}\cdot\frac{\Gamma(1-\frac{2}{\alpha})\cdot\Gamma(n+\frac{2}{\alpha})}{\Gamma(n)}$$

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. By making the change of variable
$$
t=\frac{1}{1+c\cdot r^{-\alpha}}, \quad r=c^{1/\alpha}\left(\frac1t-1 \right)^{-1/\alpha}, \quad dr=\frac{c^{1/\alpha}}{\alpha}\cdot t^{-2}\cdot\left(\frac1t-1 \right)^{-1/\alpha-1}dt,
$$ one gets
$$
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^\infty \left(1- \frac{1}{(1+c\cdot r^{-\alpha})^n}\right) 2r\cdot dr
\\\\&=-\frac{2c^{2/\alpha}}{\alpha}\int_{0}^1 (1- t^n)(1-t)^{-2/\alpha-1}t^{2/\alpha-1}dt
\\\\&=\frac{2c^{2/\alpha}}{\alpha}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_{0}^1 (1-t)^{-2/\alpha}t^{k+2/\alpha-1}dt
\\\\&=\frac{2c^{2/\alpha}}{\alpha}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{\Gamma(1-\frac{2}{\alpha})\cdot\Gamma(k+\frac{2}{\alpha})}{\Gamma(k+1)}.
\end{align}
$$ where we have used the [Euler beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).

Comment: Hello Mr.Olivier. Thank you very much for the hint, and sorry me for the late answer. I need just some more clarification. I continue your reasoning, and I find as below:  $$ \begin{align} I &=  \frac{2c^{2/\alpha}}{\alpha}\int_{0}^1(1-t)^{-2/\alpha-1}t^{2/\alpha-1}dt - \frac{2c^{2/\alpha}}{\alpha}\int_{0}^1 (1-t)^{-2/\alpha-1}t^{n+2/\alpha-1}dt                                                                      \\\\&=  \frac{2c^{2/\alpha}}{\alpha} \left( B( \frac{2}{\alpha}  ; \frac{-2}{\alpha} ) - B( n+ \frac{2}{\alpha}  ; \frac{-2}{\alpha} ) \right)                        \end{align} $$

Comment: No problem. If you write this in terms of $\Gamma$, you should obtain the announced result.

Comment: $$  I = \frac{2c^{2/\alpha}}{\alpha} \left(  \frac{\Gamma(\frac{2}{\alpha}).\Gamma(\frac{-2}{\alpha}) }{\Gamma(0)} -  \frac{\Gamma(n+ \frac{2}{\alpha}).\Gamma(\frac{-2}{\alpha}) }{\Gamma(n)} \right) $$  So the first term go to 0, like $ \Gamma(0) $ go to infinity. and with $ - \frac{2}{\alpha}. \Gamma(\frac{-2}{\alpha})= \Gamma(1 - \frac{2}{\alpha}) $ , we got the result.  Is that approach true ? because I see that for Beta function B(x,y), Re(x) and Re(y) should be positifs. and for Gamma function, is it defined at 0 ? Can we talk about $ \Gamma(0) $ ?

Comment: @adil I've edited my hint. Thanks.